# Registering Firebase as an identity provider for Tapkey

Tags: firebase-authentication, tapkey

I am working on an App which uses Firebase for authentication, and I wish to exchange the token I get back from Firebase Auth for a Tapkey token using their [Token Exchange API](https://developers.tapkey.io/api/authentication/token_exchange/).

The form to add an identity provider has four fields, I am trying with the following values:

- Name -> Firebase
- Audience -> Using my Firebase Project ID ([as described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens))
- Issuer -> https://securetoken.google.com/(projectId) ([as described here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens))
- Public Key -> Have tried both of the public keys listed [here](https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/securetoken@system.gserviceaccount.com), neither are valid (error when submitting the form)

Which are the correct values to use with adding Firebase Auth as an Identity Provider to Tapkey?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are no public keys, they are certificates. The form expects a public key in pem format, which starts with *-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----*.

You have to extract the public key from the certificate. You can do that with openssl. Save the certificate as *cert.pem*, make sure to replace the "\n" with line breaks and use the following openssl command:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem  > pubkey.pem
```